# Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

A current of $18$ amperes branches into currents $x$, $y$, and $z$ through resistors with resistances $5$, $7$, and $4$ ohms as shown.[image]

It is known that the current splits in such a way that the sum of the currents through the three resistors equals the initial current.(Kirchhoff Law). The energy generated in each resistor is given by $E=I^2R$, where $I$ is the current in that resistor and $R$ is the resistance. Use Lagrange multipliers to find the currents $x$, $y$, and $z$ which will minimize the total energy generated. (It turns out that nature always splits the currents so that the total energy is minimized.)

Comment: What difficulty are you having?

Comment: Well I believe the constraint is g(x,y,z)=x+y+z with g(x,y,z)=18.  Yet I'm unsure what f is. I guess that it would be 
f(x,y,z)=I^2R-E, But I'm not sure.

Comment: I believe once I know the function and the constraints I'll be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since $E=I^2 R$, the total energy should be

$$E=x^2 R_1+y^2 R_2 +z^2 R_3$$

where $x,y,z$ are the currents through each resistors. This is the function you want to minimize. Can you continue from here?

Comment: That makes sense, but when I used the constraint x+y+z=18 I got x=y=z and then 3x=18. So x=y=z=6. Which wasn't correct.

Comment: You made some mistake in your computation. They shouldn't be the same, since $R_1,R_2,R_3$ are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since the energy generated in each resistor is given by $E=I^2 R$ and $E_{\text{total}}=E_1+E_2+E_3+\cdots$ in general, your function to minimize is:
$$f(x,y,z)=5x^2+7y^2+4z^2$$
And your constraint is correct since $I_{\text{total}}=I_1+I_2+I_3+\cdots$ in general.
$$g(x,y,z)=x+y+z-18$$
Therefore:
$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)-\lambda\cdot g(x,y,z)=5x^2+7y^2+4z^2-\lambda(x+y+z-18)$$
Where $\lambda$ is some scalar.
We now evaluate partial derivatives and set them each equal to zero:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=10x-\lambda=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y}=14y-\lambda=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial z}=8z-\lambda=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda}=18-x-y-z=0$$
Now, just simply solve this system.